# Best practice for nested constructors

Tags: javascript, oop

I am relatively new to OOP in JS so bear with me a bit.

Lets say I have a `Restaurant` constructor function. I want to assign `Menu` objects created through a constructor to each restaurant. However, I want to be able to access properties of the parent `Restaurant` in the `Menu`'s methods.

What is the best way to do this?

This code does the job:

```
    // Restaurant constructor
    function Restaurant(name, inventory){
        this.name = name;
        this.inventory = inventory;

        var self = this;

        // Menu constructor
        this.Menu = function(items){
            this.items = items;

            // Checks whether an item is available in the menu AND the restaurant's stock
            this.isAvailable = function(item){
                if(this.items.indexOf(item) !== -1 && self.inventory.indexOf(item) !== -1){
                    console.log(item + ' is available in ' + self.name)
                }else{
                    console.log(item + ' is not available in ' + self.name);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    // First restaurant and its menus
    var Diner = new Restaurant('diner', ['steak', 'fish', 'salad']);
    var Entrees = new Diner.Menu(['steak', 'fish']);
    var Appetizers = new Diner.Menu(['shrimp']);

    // Not available, since salad isn't in the menu
    Entrees.isAvailable('salad');
    // Available, since fish is in stock and in the menu
    Entrees.isAvailable('fish');
    // Not available, since shrimp is not in stock
    Appetizers.isAvailable('shrimp');

    // Different restaurant and its menus
    var BurgerJoint = new Restaurant('burger joint', ['burger', 'fries', 'ketchup']);
    var Sides = new BurgerJoint.Menu(['ketchup', 'fries']);
    var Lunch = new BurgerJoint.Menu(['fries', 'burger', 'mustard']);

    Sides.isAvailable('salad');
    Sides.isAvailable('fries');
    Lunch.isAvailable('mustard');
```

However, this produces the pitfall that the isAvailable method (and other similar methods) cannot be moved to the prototype, because they rely on having the `Restaurant`'s properties through that `self` property. The closest it can come is replacing the `Menu` constructor with this:

```
        var self = this;

        // Menu constructor
        this.Menu = function(items){
            this.items = items;
        }
        this.Menu.prototype = {
            isAvailable:function(item){
                //...
            }
        }
```

This still creates a new prototype for each `Restaurant`, however, although it does share the prototype across menus in a restaurant. Still doesn't feel ideal.

Another option is disassociating the `Menu` constructor with the `Restaurant`, and passing in the `Restaurant` object when creating a new Menu. Like this:

```
    // Restaurant constructor
    function Restaurant(name, inventory){
        this.name = name;
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }

    // Menu constructor
    function Menu(restaurant, items){
        this.restaurant = restaurant
        this.items = items;
    }

    Menu.prototype = {
        isAvailable:function(item){
            if(this.items.indexOf(item) !== -1 && this.restaurant.inventory.indexOf(item) !== -1){
                console.log(item + ' is available in ' + this.restaurant.name)
            }else{
                console.log(item + ' is not available in ' + this.restaurant.name);
            }
        }
    }
```

New menus are created like so:

```
    var Entrees = new Menu(Diner, ['steak', 'fish']);
```

This feels wrong, mostly because the syntax is non-intuitive, and the `Menu`s aren't inherently linked to the `Restaurant`.

So, what's the right way of doing this? Any of these? A different way entirely?

Comment: Menu's shouldn't intherit from Restaurant!? they are different things which just play together

Comment: And this kind of question belongs more to Code Review

Comment: What is so non-intuitive in `new Menu(Dinner, ...` vs `new Dinner.Menu(..`?

Comment: Go with the last option (Menu's construction function takes a parameter that is the Restaurant) and then add a helper method in Restaurant that will call Menu's constructor while passing in the reference to the Restaurant creating the Menu.  If you really must have bidirectional references between Restaurant and Menu I think that's the cleanest alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The prototype is something that you build UPON, don't build a-new. For example, you had:

```
    this.Menu.prototype = {
        isAvailable:function(item){
            //...
        }
    }
```

... which is essentially replacing the prototype with ONE object... while you won't go to jail for doing that, it does requires you to do all "construction" within the context of that one object. yuck.

Here's a model based on your situation that will serve you well moving forward. I've been using this approach for years. It's very flexible and extensible -- and feels (and sorta-kinda looks) like "real" programming (e.g. java, C#, etc.) rather than garbly goo jquery.

You'll notice that we build INTO the prototype through a neat "p" variable. I also like to defer initializing out to a function so we can keep the constructor toward the top.

```
// ------------------------
// Restaurant "class"
// ------------------------
function Restaurant(params){
    this.init(params);
}

var p = Restaurant.prototype;

    // I like to define "properties" on the prototype here so I'm aware of all the properties in this "class"
    p.name = null;
    p.inventory = null; // Don't put arrays or objects on the prototype. Just don't, initialize on each instance.
    p.menus = null;

    p.init = function(params){
        this.name = params.name;
        this.inventory = params.inventory || []; // default to empty array so indexOf doesn't break
        this.menus = {};

        if(params.menus){
            for(var prop in params.menus){
                this.addMenu(prop, params.menus[prop]);
            }
        }

    }

    p.addMenu = function(name, items){
        this.menus[name] = new Menu({
            restaurant : this,
            items : items
        });
    }

    p.getMenu = function(name){
        return this.menus[name];
    }

// ------------------------
// Menu "class"
// ------------------------
function Menu(params){
    this.init(params);
}

var p = Menu.prototype;

    p.items = null;
    p.restaurant = null;

    p.init = function(params){
        this.items = params.items || []; // default to an empty array
        this.restaurant = params.restaurant;
    }

    p.isAvailable = function(item){
        if(this.items.indexOf(item) !== -1 && this.restaurant.inventory.indexOf(item) !== -1){
            console.log(item + ' is available in ' + this.restaurant.name)
        }else{
            console.log(item + ' is not available in ' + this.restaurant.name);
        }
    }

// First restaurant and its menus
var Diner = new Restaurant({
    name        : 'diner',
    inventory   : ['steak', 'fish', 'salad'],
    menus : {
        entrees     : ['steak', 'fish'],
        // appetizers   : ['shrimp'] // maybe add this a different way (below)
    }

});

// ... add a menu another way
Diner.addMenu('appetizers', ['shrimp']);



// Not available, since salad isn't in the menu
Diner.menus.entrees.isAvailable('salad');
// Available, since fish is in stock and in the menu
Diner.getMenu('entrees').isAvailable('fish');
// Not available, since shrimp is not in stock
Diner.menus.appetizers.isAvailable('shrimp');
// or
// Diner.getMenu('appetizers').isAvailable('shrimp');
```

For what it's worth, I also like to wrap each class up into a closure and have each class as it's own file:

```
// ------------------------
// Restaurant "class"
// ------------------------

// Start the closure
this.myApp = this.myApp || {};
(function(){


// All this is the same as above ...
function Restaurant(params){
    this.init(params);
}

var p = Restaurant.prototype;

    p.init = function(){
    ... yada ...


// Here we finish the closure and add the primary function as a property
//  to the "myApp" global object. So I'm essentially building up "myApp"
// kinda the same way as we built up the prototype.
    myApp.Restaurant = Restaurant;
());
```

I'll put that into it's own file then during development, just do a < script src="..." > for each class into my HTML. And for production I can then combine all the files.

Under this approach, to use it would be:

```
var Diner = new myApp.Restaurant({
    name        : 'diner',
    inventory   : ['steak', 'fish', 'salad'],
    menus : {
        entrees     : ['steak', 'fish'],
        // appetizers   : ['shrimp'] 
    }

});

// ... and the rest is the same as above.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Object hierachy shouldn't be reflected as *constructor function nesting*. In fact, what you're doing isn't *inheritance*  but ***composition***.

Thus, you should define each entity as top-level constructors and create the object graph with actual instances:

```
var menu = new Menu();
var restaurant = new Restaurant(menu);
```

What demonstrates that **restaurant *HAS A* menu**? The fact that a restaurant will access its menu this way: `restaurant.menu`.

In object-oriented programming **is verb** means inheritance, while **has verb** means **aggregation**.

### How to associate a menu with a concrete restaurant?

It's just about this:

```
var menu = new Menu();
var restaurant = new Restaurant(menu);
menu.restaurant = restaurant;
```

This would be a *one-to-one* association. It might happen that you could need to share a menu across many restaurants. Then you would do it as follows:

```
var menu = new Menu();
var restaurant = new Restaurant(menu);
menu.restaurants.push(restaurant);
```

So `Menu` constructor should initialize `this.restaurants`:

```
function Menu() {
    this.restaurants = [];
}
```

Comment: What I don't like about this approach is that it violates good encapsulation because the caller now needs to be aware of a key implementation detail - that a Menu can only be associated with at most one Restaurant.  Trying to do a "chain restaurant" and sharing one Menu among more than one Restaurant would fail because you'd overwrite the Menu -> Restaurant reference, but the API doesn't make that assumption clear.  I'd prefer an interface where the Restaurant would directly handle menu creation, which makes it a little more clear that the created Menu is strongly tied to the Restaurant.

Comment: @PMV Is it fine now?

Comment: Yeah, it's more clear now.  Really I think the best option of all is to make Menu not need the reference to Restaurant to begin with.  The other option is just to make Restaurant always construct a Menu item when the Restaurant is constructed, and expose that already-constructed Menu via a property.

Comment: @PMV Uhm, but from my perspective, I always tend to model my object graph based on the real-world case. If a menu can be of more than a restaurant, it means that it should hold many references to restaurants.

Comment: @PMV After all, you'll want to navigate through your object graph. If you get a menu and you want to see which restaurants own the same menu, if you don't go this way, you'll need to do a query, which is heavier than just getting the whole associated collection (i.e. array...)

Comment: I agree completely about basing it on the real world case, but I try to reduce the level to which objects "know about" each other down to what they minimally need to do their job, and couple the objects more loosely.  If it's an important use case that a user be able to query Restaurants from a Menu, I'd do it, but in general bidirectional references need a lot of "care and feeding" to ensure they never get out of sync, and they tightly couple objects which can make testing more challenging.  Sometimes it's unavoidable, of course.